# POST to REST API from winform returns empty

Tags: c#, json, winforms, post

I have a project that uses the [hockeystreams.com API](https://www4.hockeystreams.com/api#login).  I am having trouble with using their API to login from my WinForm.  It always gives me a blank response, whether I give a bad username/password combination or a correct one.  My code is as follows:

```
public static bool LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        string URL = string.Format("{0}&username={1}&password={2}", Global.LOGIN_API, username, password);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        try
        {

            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string json = "";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    json += reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            LogInJSON deserializedLogInData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogInJSON>(json);
            if (deserializedLogInData.Status == "Success")
            {
                Global.TOKEN = deserializedLogInData.Token;
                Global.USERNAME = deserializedLogInData.Username;
                Global.ISPREMIUM = deserializedLogInData.Membership == "REGULAR" ? false : true;
                Global.FAVORITETEAM = deserializedLogInData.Favteam;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I have tried changing the POST to PUT, but that throws a 406 error (Bad Request).  I am very green with JSON so I don't know where to go from here.  Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I found this on the hockeystreams website that is similar to my issue but the are using apache httpclient.

```
    With buckinpgh's help I resolved my issue.

Just for anyone else out there who is wondering, the solution (if your using apache HttpClient) is to create a HttpPost request with the url: "https://api.hockeystreams.com/Login?"

then add two headers:
1) StringEntity with the value: "username=<username>&password=<password>&key=<apiKey>"
2) "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

after that you can just call HttpClient.execute with your request. Of course you'll have to parse the json result, but at least now you have a result.
```

I changed my code to try and follow it as best I could with the HttpWebRequest:

```
public static bool LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        string URL = Global.LOGIN_PATH;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("StringEntity", string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&key={2}", username, password, Global.APIKEY);
        try 
        {
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string json = "";
```

But it still comes back with a blank response.  Is there a different way around this I'm not seeing?

EDIT 2:

Ended up with this code fixing it.   I used RestSharp for this.

```
public static bool LogIn(string username, string password)
        {
            string URL = Global.LOGIN_PATH;
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://api.hockeystreams.com/");
                var request = new RestRequest("login?", Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-forms-urlencoded");
                request.AddParameter("username", username);
                request.AddParameter("password", password);
                request.AddParameter("key", Global.APIKEY);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                var json = response.Content;

                LogInJSON deserializedLogInData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogInJSON>(json);

                try
                {
                    if (deserializedLogInData.Status == "Success")
                    {
                        Global.TOKEN = deserializedLogInData.Token;
                        Global.USERNAME = deserializedLogInData.Username;
                        Global.ISPREMIUM = deserializedLogInData.Membership == "REGULAR" ? false : true;
                        Global.FAVORITETEAM = deserializedLogInData.Favteam;

                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Global.ERROR = deserializedLogInData.Msg;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the key in the URL as (outlined by the documentation):

```
https://api.hockeystreams.com/Login?username=<username>&password=<password>&key=<api_key>
```

Comment: That is how it was originally done, but it returns a blank response.  It seems from reading the API discussion on HS it has to be sent through the  body.  http://www4.hockeystreams.com/assist/categories/13/api+discussion/779/HockeyStreams+API

Comment: If what you posted is "how it was originally done" then you're missing the API key. This:

`string URL = string.Format("{0}&username={1}&password={2}", Global.LOGIN_API, username, password);`

Should be this:
`string URL = string.Format("{0}&username={1}&password={2}&key={3}", Global.LOGIN_API, username, password,Global.APIKEY);`

Comment: Putting it in the body would be my next suggestion, but you will need to serialize it first.

Comment: The key is in the Global.LOGIN_API string,  The parameters do not have to be in ordered (which I can confirm)

Comment: Maybe try it ordered. And try it in the body. If neither works, I would recommend taking .NET out of the equation by using a REST client like Postman

Comment: Tried it ordered, same issue.  I have never heard of postman, but I downloaded RestSharp from NuGet and am reformating it with that, but having the same issue.

Comment: [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) is a chrome extension. You can use it to test APIs. If the problem is with the web service, you'll have the same issue on there

Comment: Aha.  I will have to keep that in mind.  I don't often use Chrome, but I'm sure Maxthon has something similar.